# Flutter Firebase initialization problem for Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, build.gradle

In my flutter project that is connected to Firebase, I can run the signup and the signin pages without any problems on IOS. However, with Android, I see the following problems on the debug console:
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:64170/arF7rSsBtVk=/ws
E/flutter ( 4695): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource.

google-services.json is located correctly at android/app. When I run it on android emulator, I see a blank page with these problems. what can I do about this?

I checked the packages names and saw no discrepancies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First check the pubspec.yaml file and check if the versions of Firebase packages are up to date.

Check the gradle versions and compatabilities.

Try `flutter clean` and refresh the project.

Try testing it on a real device, sometimes it might not work with the virtual devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my error was:

```
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:58547/pz_fzr28_Hc=/ws
E/flutter ( 9471): [ERROR: flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from the resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java. lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from the resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.
```

I followed this [instruction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0&_gl=1*1a2szw*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTEzMDk1MjI4Ni4xNzEwODU3NzQ0*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcxMDkyNDg3OS4yLjEuMTcxMDkyNTU5MS41My4wLjA.#analytics-not-enabled), as I saw on YouTube, but the correct one is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?authuser=0&_gl=1*kkdz08*_up*MQ..*_ga*MTEzMDk1MjI4Ni4xNzEwODU3NzQ0*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTcxMDkyNDg3OS4yLjEuMTcxMDkyNTU5OS40NS4wLjA.&platform=ios)